# space of probability for an infinite sequence of coin flips

Tags: probability, probability-theory, uniform-distribution

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be the usual space of probability for an infinite sequence of coin flips. Let $X$ be the function from $\Omega$ to $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathcal{B})$ defined by
$$
X((w_1,w_2,\ldots))=(0.w_1w_3w_5\dots two,0.w_2w_4w_6\dots two )
$$

($two = binary$)

Here I understand that the distribution of $X$ is a generalization of the area, restricted to  the unit square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, i.e,
$$
Q([a,b]\times[c,d]) = (b-a)(d-c) = area([a,b]\times[c,d]) 
$$

For the random variable $X=(X_1,X_2)$: How can I calculate the probability that $X_1+X_2 \geq 1/2$, well I first try to calculate 
$$
P(X_1+X_2\geq 1/2) = P (\{ w: X(w_1)+X(w_2) \geq 1/2\})
$$

but now I don't know how to continue calculating this probability if I have that
$$
X((w_1,w_2,\ldots))=(0.w_1w_3w_5\dots two,0.w_2w_4w_6\dots two )
$$
because we have only $w_1$ and $w_2$ then Is it true that

$$
X((w_1,w_2))=(0.w_1,0.w_2) ?
$$
Someone could help me calculating this probability in this space please...

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: As a search term you might look up Bernoulli trials.

Comment: I don´t know about types of distributions yet, this is an example of my fourth class that I´m trying to understand, I just know the definition of  a , measure space, lebesgue integral, random variable and propositions in measure theory, It is difficult for me understand experimental cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X_1 = 0.\omega_1\omega_3\omega_5\ldots_{\mathsf{two}}$ which is to say a binary fraction generated by the digits $\omega_1,\omega_3,\omega_5$, and so on.   Each of which is either $0$ or $1$ as assigned by an independent coin flip.

$X_1$ is thus a *continuous uniformly distributed random* variable over the support $[0;1]\cap \Bbb Q$.

$X_2$ is likewise defined, and independently so from $X_1$.  (Since it it defined by the infinite set of 'even' indexed coin flips.)

Hence $X(\omega) ~{= (X_1(\omega_1,\omega_3,\omega_5,\ldots),X_2(\omega_2,\omega_4,\omega_6,\ldots)) \\ = (0.\omega_1\omega_3\omega_5\ldots_{\mathsf{two}},0.\omega_2\omega_4\omega_6\ldots_{\mathsf{two}})}$

The probability you want is $\mathsf P(\{(\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots): 0.\omega_1\omega_3\ldots_{\mathsf {two}}+0.\omega_2\omega_4\ldots_{\mathsf {two}}\geq {0.1}_{\mathsf{two}}\}) \\ = \mathsf P(0.\omega_1\omega_3\ldots_{\mathsf {two}}+0.\omega_2\omega_4\ldots_{\mathsf {two}}\geq {0.1}_{\mathsf{two}}) \\ = \mathsf P(\{\omega: X_1(\omega_{\sf odd})+X_2(\omega_{\sf even})\geq 1/2\})\\=\mathsf P(X_1+X_2\geq 1/2)\\\ldots\text{ and such}$

This is easy to find by using what is know of uniform continuous distributions, but you *could* do it knowing that the probability equals:

$${\quad{\mathsf P(\omega_1=1)+\mathsf P(\omega_1=0)\mathsf P(\omega_2=1)\\+\mathsf P(\omega_1=0)\mathsf P(\omega_2=0)\,\mathsf P(0.\omega_3\omega_5\ldots_{\textsf{two}}+0.\omega_4\omega_6\ldots_{\textsf{two}}\geq 1_{\textsf{two}})} \\ ~\vdots\\ = \tfrac 12+\tfrac 14+\tfrac 18\\ = \tfrac 78}$$

You just have to fill in the missing steps.

Comment: Why $P(X_1+X_2\geq 2)$?

Comment: It is a typo.  Clrly that was missing a $1/$

Comment: ok.............

Comment: why did you get this :$${\quad{\mathsf P(\omega_1=1)+\mathsf P(\omega_1=0)\mathsf P(\omega_2=1)\\+\mathsf P(\omega_1=0)\mathsf P(\omega_2=0)\,\mathsf P(0.\omega_3\omega_5\ldots_{\textsf{two}}+0.\omega_4\omega_6\ldots_{\textsf{two}}\geq 1_{\textsf{two}})} \\}$$ ?

Comment: The sum will be at least $0.1_\mathsf{two}$ if the first digit of either decimal is $1$, or else if they are both zero and the sum of the remaining expressions is $0.1_\mathsf{two}$ or more (which would require...).

Comment: So then I have to calculate the integral from 1/2 to 1 and the othe integral from 1/2 to 1/2-x ?

Comment: I´m trying to understand this but its complicate for me...

Comment: @Knight Yes: $~\displaystyle\mathsf P(X_1+X_2\geq 1/2)~=~\int_0^{1/2}\int_{(1/2)-x}^1 1\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x+ \int_{1/2}^1 1\,\mathrm d x$

Comment: Just for be sure that I understand For example if I need the $P(X_1+X_2>2/3)$, Can I take a similar reasoning and then compute the integrals from 0 to 2/3 integral from (2/3)-x to 1 plus intregla from 2/3 to 1 ?

Comment: For sure : $\mathsf P(X_1+X_2\geq 2/3) ~{~=~ \int_0^{2/3}\int_{(2/3) -x}^1 1\mathrm d y~\mathrm d x+\int_{2/3}^1 1 \mathrm d x \\ ~=~ 1-\int_0^{2/3}\int_0^{(2/3)-x} 1\mathrm d y\mathrm d x \\ ~=~ \tfrac 79}$

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: You say $X_1$ is a *continuous uniformly distributed random variable* with "support" on $[0;1]\cap \Bbb Q$.  The countable set $\Bbb Q$ is of measure zero in the unit interval $[0,1]$, which causes problems if we try and restrict a continuous uniformly distributed random variable from the real unit interval to the rational values there with any fidelity to the usual uniform probability measure.  Also the identification of binary sequences with points in the unit interval fails to be unambiguous at some (not all) rational values. Perhaps you were trying to *exclude* $\Bbb Q$?

Answer (score 2):

SInce each of $X_1,X_2$ can be considered a uniformly distributed random variate on $[0,1]$, and they are not correlated, what you are looking for is the probability that the sum of two such variates exceeds $\frac12$.

Geometrically, that corresponds to the area of the unit square lying above the line $x+y=\frac12$.  Since the triangle defined by $(0,0),(\frac12,0),(0\frac12)$ has area $\frac18$ the probability you are looking for is 
$$
1-\frac18 = \frac78
$$

Comment: Sorry for this question but How can I understand the function $X((w_1,w_2,\ldots))=(0.w_1w_3w_5\dots two,0.w_2w_4w_6\dots two )$ ?

Comment: The text of your question already defined $X_1=0.w_1w_3w_5\dots_\mathrm{two}$ and $X_2 = 0.w_2w_4w_6\dots_\mathrm{two}$. So this answer is telling you exactly what you should know about $0.w_1w_3w_5\dots_\mathrm{two}$ and $0.w_2w_4w_6\dots_\mathrm{two},$ just using the more convenient symbols $X_1$ and $X_2.$

Comment: Go flip an *infinite* count of 1-0 faced coins.  On every odd flip, you append the result to end of the binary decimal $X_1$, and on every even flip, you append the result to the end of the binary decimal $X_2$.  Come back when you are finished, and you will have an ordered pair of binary decimals, $(X_1,X_2)$ which you can call $X$.

Comment: For example if I need the $P(X_1+X_2 > \frac{2}{3})$, Can I take the triganle again but now with $(0,0)$,  $( \frac{2}{3},0)$ and $(0, \frac{2}{3})$ 
 then the area is $2/9$ and the probability is $1-(2/9) =  7/9$?

Comment: Yes, that works and gives the right answer.  Of course, the geometry becomes slightly different if you are asking the probability that the sum be greater than some more than $1$.